# Related Record Component on Community Builder

Tags: community, lightning-experience, lightning-community, community-builder

I'm using the Community Builder to customize the Details layout of a few objects.
Part of what we want is to show a few fields of a related object. For example, let's say I'm showing the `Contact` record, I want to be able to show a few fields of the related `Account` record. Something like `Contact.Account.Name`.
Now, I know that there is a Lightning Component called `Related Record` which does exactly that.
But here's the thing: I can't see that component in the doohickey on the left in the Builder. I can see it in the regular Lightning App Builder page for this object, but not in the community.
I tried making a custom Action for `update` as I've seen recommended, but it's still not working.
Is it a template thing? Is this just not available for Communities? Is there something else I could try?

Comment: what is you Community templates [version ?](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_networks_commbuilder_view_template_version.htm) This component is supported in [API version 39.0 and later](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components.htm&type=5)

Comment: the related record component is based on an available add/edit action for the object - did you add an action for the object?

Comment: There already exist actions for Create. I added one for Update.

Answer (score 1):

If its not visible in communities implies that its not available for communities as there is no specific settings/config to make it available in communities.

One out of the box solution is to use a product from Salesforce Labs called "Enhanced Lightning Grid". Based on your requirement it looks like this will suit your use case.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EVK8iUAH

Comment: Have you seen anywhere in the official docs that says this is not available to Communities? Products on the AppExchange are not the answer to this question, nor a good solution.

Comment: I cant find the doc to indicate this behaviour, You have to raise a case to get justification from SF end for this. Also SF is built on config first pattern, if one can get things done by installing a free product, which would save code hours and is robust(Its built by SF to add features which are not in standard feature-set) its a good solution.

Comment: **Idea** for [this](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000019OoQQAU)